# jquery script doesn't access my radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html

i have the following dropdown button with radio buttons inside and i want a jquery script to do some stuff depending on which radio button is pressed but the event is never triggered. here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('input:radio[name="field"]').change(function () {
            alert("pipa");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="button-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select learning outcome field</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="radio" name="field" value="al" checked /> Algorithms and Complexity (AL)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="radio" name="field" value="gv" /> Graphics and Visualization (GV) </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="radio" name="field" value="hci" /> Human-Computer Interaction (HCI)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="radio" name="field" value="is" /> Intelligent Systems (IS)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="radio" name="field" value="nc" /> Networking and Communication (NC)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="radio" name="field" value="os" /> Operating Systems (OS)</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't put your radios in links, they are both interactive elements and they behave erratically ifr nested within each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me, just not as you intended I think...

Right now, your code is only set up to trigger when the radio button is clicked (that works for me with your code). The function won't fire if you click the link text because the listener is attached to the inputs and not the list item.

Make sure you have the script linked or embedded in your html document that you wish to have your jQuery code effect. I didn't see any inline script or external  script in your example (other than the jQuery library.)